# ¿Como puedo setear una fecha en el dia actual?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo 2 imput de tipo datetimepicker`date_start & date end` y datepicker `date_reincorporation`, cuando eligo la misma fecha en el 1ro necesito que el segundo guarde la fecha actual puesto que si un usuario se toma una licencia un mismo dia el dia de reincorporacion es el mismo. Gracias

```
<el-form-item label="Reintegro:" prop="date_reincorporation" v-if="ifSameDay === false">
                  <el-date-picker v-model="form.date_reincorporation"
                                  type="date"
                                  v-mask="'##-##-####'"
                                  format="dd-MM-yyyy"
                                  value-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
                                  :picker-options="pickerOptions"
                                  placeholder="Fecha de reincorporación">
                  </el-date-picker>
                </el-form-item>
ifSameDay() {
    const date_start = moment(this.form.dates[0]).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    const date_end = moment(this.form.dates[1]).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    return (date_start === date_end && date_start !== 'Invalid date') ? true : false;
  },
```

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres decir es que si las primeras dos fechas son iguales, la reincorporación también sea igual a las dos primeras. ¿Tiene sentido? Yo diría que la fecha de reincorporación debiera ser el día siguiente a `date_end`

Comment: no por que una licencia puede ser en mi caso de 4,5,6 hs de una jornada laboral de 8, el tema es que cuando la fecha es igual el datepicker se desabilita y aunque no lo desabilite igual no se guarda la fecha.

Comment: Te dejé una respuesta. El hecho que no se guarde la fecha de reincorporación se debe a que no estás definiendo la fecha de reincorporación en `ifSameDay`. Luego, sacas el input pero la propiedad nunca la fijaste. Me gusta más la idea de tratar `ifSameDay` como un método que se ejecuta cuando cambian los dos primeros input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me imagino que estás usando el datepicker de [element-ui](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker)

Lo que yo haría es:

- Definir las propiedades `date_start` y `date_end` como `computed`
- Al cambiar sus valores, en el `setter` ejecutar  `ifSameDay` como método, no como propiedad `computed`.
- En el setter de `date_start` y `date_end` fijas el valor de `this.form.dates[0]` y `this.form.dates[1]`, puesto que definir propiedades anidadas como computed es un problema. El getter de esas dos propiedades, a su vez, devuelve los valores de `this.form.dates`.
- Al ejecutar `ifSameDay`, si se cumple la condición, fijar `this.form.date_reincorporation` a la fecha que quieres, y fijar una propiedad `this.reincorporation_readonly` como `true` para bloquear el input.
- Si no se cumple la condición, limpiar `this.form.date_reincorporation` y definir `this.reincorporation_readonly` como `false`.

El input de la fecha de reincorporación quedaría:

Y te ahorras envolver el parent en un v-if.

Si tu componente hoy tiene la estructura (voy a simplificar mucho)

```
{
  name: 'Licencias',
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        dates: [new Date(), new Date()],
        date_reincorporation: new Date()
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ifSameDay() {
      const date_start = moment(this.form.dates[0]).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      const date_end = moment(this.form.dates[1]).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      return (date_start === date_end && date_start !== 'Invalid date') ? true : false;
    },
  }
};
```

Con mi sugerencia quedaría:

```
{
  name: 'Licencias',
  data() {
    return {
      reincorporation_readonly: false,
      form: {
        dates: [new Date(), new Date()],
        date_reincorporation: new Date()
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    date_start: {
      get() {
        return this.form.dates[0];
      },
      set(date_start) {
        this.form.dates[0] = date_start;
        this.ifSameDay();
      },
    },
    date_end: {
      get() {
        return this.form.dates[1];
      },
      set(date_start) {
        this.form.dates[1] = date_end;
        this.ifSameDay();
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ifSameDay() {
      const date_start = moment(this.form.dates[0]).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      const date_end = moment(this.form.dates[1]).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      if (date_start === date_end && date_start !== 'Invalid date') {
        this.form.date_reincorporation = date_end;
        this.reincorporation_readonly = true;
      }
    },
  }
};
```

En otras palabras, el `v-model` de la fecha inicio y fecha fin apunta a `date_start` y `date_end`, las cuales modifican *indirectamente* `this.form.dates`. La gracia es que al ponerle getters y setters puedes gatillar el efecto colateral de comprobar `ifSameDay` en el cual fijas la fecha de reincorporación y dejas el input como readonly. En este caso, no hay un `v-if` en el `el-form-item`.

Este es sólo un posible enfoque. También podrías añadir un watcher a las propiedades, pero eso me parece más sucio.

Finalmente, también podrías forzar la fecha de reincorporación al hacer submit sin tocar el resto de tu código, pero tendrías que hacer dos comprobaciones:

```
submitForm() {

    this.form.date_reincorporation = this.ifSameDay? this.form.date[1] : this.form.date_reincorporation;

    this.form.date_reincorporation = this.form.date_reincorporation?  moment(this.form.date_reincorporation).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') : null; 

}
```

Comment: entiendo la solucion pero no se como aplicarlo, hace poco estoy con este sistema, por eso decia de como puedo devolver en ifSameDay la fecha de reintegro, sí uso element-ui

Comment: si mal no entiendo igual en el submit está guardando date_reincorporation como nulo cuando ifSameDay = true?         this.form.date_reincorporation = (this.form.date_reincorporation && !this.ifSameDay) ? moment(this.form.date_reincorporation).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') : null;

Comment: Según ese comentario, efectivamente estás guardando como nulo el valor, y entiendo que no es lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Te dejé un ejemplo muy simplificado de cómo quedaría tu componente. A ver si te sirve